# Push Notifications on a Button Tap event

Tags: windows-iot, c#

I am working on Universal Windows Platform(IOT-UWP). I want to fire a push notification at a button tap event. Is there any way of doing it? or is it even possible? Also, if my IoT device receives a push notification, is there any way I can perform some actions as soon as a notification arrives assuming the IoT UWP application is running and the user has can't tap on the notification. Can I handle such an event?

Comment: This is all completely achievable, but it's really a software question, not specific to the pi. I'd suggest re-asking it on StackOverflow.

Comment: @goobering Yes, I did post it there. I just thought that because it's an IoT based question someone in the community might have tried something on the same note. Anyways thank you :)